# Why this function increase the memory usage?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is my code.

```
private string ConvertOriginalDataListToString(List<string> originalDataList)
    {
        string totalOriginalData = string.Empty;
    
        foreach (var eachOriginalData in originalDataList)
        {
            if (totalOriginalData == string.Empty)
            {
                totalOriginalData = eachOriginalData;
            }
            else
            {
                totalOriginalData = totalOriginalData + "," + eachOriginalData;
            }
        }
    
        return totalOriginalData;
    }
```

before running this function. the memory usually use 60MB.
but while running this function. the memory use over 200MB.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But, when i use StringBuilder instead. the memory issue has solved.

```
private string ConvertOriginalDataListToString(List<string> originalDataList)
    {
        StringBuilder totalOriginalData = new StringBuilder();
    
        foreach (var eachOriginalData in originalDataList)
        {
            totalOriginalData.Append(eachOriginalData);
            totalOriginalData.Append(",");
        }
    
        totalOriginalData.Remove(totalOriginalData.Length - 1, 1);
    
        return totalOriginalData.ToString();
    }
```

I think this issue associated with local variable and memory allocation.
please let me know under below.

1. why this function has a lot of memory
2. what is different between string+string and StringBuilder.Append

Thanks !!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTjXg.png

Comment: IMHO Use `string.Join()` to build the result. Otherwise *every* *single* `string + string` will allocate memory, which you don't care about.

Comment: [Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/) are immutable and you are creating a lot of them

Comment: Suggest to the garbage collector that it should run then re-measure memory usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1):

The `StringBuilder` class exists specifically for this reason. Every time you concatenate two `string` objects, you create a new `string` object that contains the combined characters of the other two. As `strings` get long, that obviously becomes a problem. If you do this:

```cs
var substrings = new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
var str = string.Empty;

foreach (var substring in substrings)
{
    str += substring;
}
```

then you will create the following `string` objects in that loop:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

As you can imagine, if the substrings were long and numerous, that would eat up memory pretty quickly. There is an overhead with using a `StringBuilder` but I've read that, once you get to about a dozen concatenations, the additional efficiency of avoiding all the extra allocations overrides that overhead and the difference only increases. You should generally use methods of the `String` class, e.g. `Concat` or `Join`, in fairly simple cases and a `StringBuilder` directly for complex cases.

As a general rule, I never use more than a single concatenation in one place. I either use string interpolation (`string.Format` in older versions) or a method like `string.Concat` or a `StringBuilder`.

In your specific case, you should be using this:

```cs
var totalOriginalData = string.Join(",", originalDataList);
```

One line and done. You don't even need your method, because you can do that where you'd otherwise be calling your method.